# PhoneGap Geolocation get always a timeout on special devices

Tags: android, cordova

I use cordova 2.9.0 with PhoneGap Build. I have written an app where a user can check-in on special location to a special time.
My problem is that when I install de app on various devices I sometimes get always a timout (this occurs only on Android devices). When I restart the device the geolocation works and I get the gps-data. Now I'd like to know if there is another way to resolve this problem.
My code for geolocation in the deviceReady function is:

```
var geo = cordova.require('cordova/plugin/geolocation');
var optionsGeo = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
var watchID = geo.watchPosition(onSuccessGeo, errorGeo, optionsGeo);

function onSuccessGeo(position) {
  lat = (position.coords.latitude).toFixed(6);
  lon = (position.coords.longitude).toFixed(6);
  accuracy = (position.coords.accuracy).toFixed(0); 
  console.log("Lat " + lat + " Lon " + lon + " & " + accuracy + "m");
}

function errorGeo(error) {
  console.log("Geo-Fehler! Code: " + error.code + " Nachricht: " + error.message);
}
```

I have tried with different timeoutvalues and with enabled HighAccuracy - but nothing helps.
Thanks.

Comment: I have been having the same issue, did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing this issue, mainly with Samsung android devices. What I found out is that:

1. If you do not have a SIM card installed in the device, then there will be no gps coordinates (that's only applicable to some devices).
2. Please make sure that you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` set in your android manifest.
3. You should set `enableHighAccuracy:true` please see below my settings:

   `var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);`

**enableHighAccuracy** provides a hint that the application would like to receive the best possible results. By default, the device will attempt to retrieve a Position using network-based methods. Setting this property to true tells the framework to use more accurate methods, such as satellite positioning.

In some cases, developers use **[geolocation.watchPosition](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.watchPosition)** to get more accurate gps results. Can you also try that?

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I encountered the same problem today using Cordova 3.5.0 with the geolocation plugin (org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.8).

I solved it by enabling the GPS "HighAccuracy"-mode on the device (android). (Settings -> Location access -> Mode).
The app-user gets a hint that he needs to enable this option in order to use the app...